# Sealing an OSB floor in a shed

Tags: wood, floor, waterproofing

We have two sheds with OSB flooring..  We have an ATV that we use for snow removal, and it is parked in the shed before & AFTER plowing snow.  We are very concerned about "melting snow" ruining the OSB flooring and want to put down a waterproof paint/covering on the floor to repel moisture from melting snow..  Any suggestions out there???  Any & all will be appreciated. Thanks, Nancy

Comment: OSB is never a finished surface (on walls *or* floors). Folks have been misusing it that way for decades, which is partly why it has a bad reputation. I'd be overlying 3/8" plywood and painting that.

Answer (score 3):

Why not consider putting down a sheet of vinyl similar to what might be used on a kitchen or bathroom floor.

You would have to ensure that the underlying OSB flooring material was fairly solid and all joints supported. If it is just one layer of OSB you may want to start with a second layer of OSB that has the sheets installed in a manner that no joints in the first and second layer are in the same places.

Comment: Yes, except that OSB isn't a suitable substrate for vinyl. In a shed, sure, but if you're adding an underlayment, make it plywood.

Comment: I'm trying to think if the OSB can't be removed, can laying a layer of plywood over the OSB from corner to corner, and then proceed with taking the steps to layer vinyl on top of the plywood, would there be any issues? I can see the issue with gaining 1/2 inch of height, but the plus would be that floor would be pretty strong.

Comment: I had a large garage at a previous residence (28' x 36') that had a rafter truss construction that allowed for a robust standup space as an "attic". I made a full floor up there out of two layers of 1/2" thick OSB laid in so that there were not unsupported joints between sheets of the material. I did not find the OSB to be an undesirable floor material at all. 1" thick of screwed down material made a solid floor. I cannot think why vinyl laid down on top of it would have been any real sort of a real problem. For sure plywood would be better but even that does not standup well if it gets wet.

Comment: @MichaelKaras your situation was indoors, protected by a roof and a maintained environment.  A shed floor over joists is, at best, a damp location subject to all sorts of environmental abuse from blown rain and snow blown in underneath the joists, roof eaves, bottom of door, etc... condensation on both sides, animal nesting... leaves blowing underneath and accumulating... You name it.

Comment: That, and no vinyl manufacturer will warrant it, which means that it's problematic. In particular, vinyl wears very quickly if the underlayment isn't smooth. Any texture translates through the vinyl sheet and the wear layer takes a beating on the high spots. Again, for a shed, fine, put it down. But if you're adding another layer of something, make it plywood.

Answer (score 0):

As you know water and moisture will damage the OSB, but will also damage the framing underneath. Is partly the reason why you would have a roof over it.so to help thing in your situation,I would soak the area with a clear wood preservative and let it soak in,then underneath the ATV I would build some kind of a tray with possibly the sheet flooring. It would have to have raised edges (maybe sapping around the edges) and a way to drain. I ether sloped to the door or maybe just a hole to the underneath.

Comment: The shed is quite new and the OSB flooring is still in excellent shape, however I am looking for recommendations of a "paint" that I can roll onto the floor and prevent water from getting on the OSB flooring..  Could I use a roofing paint???

Comment: What about a rubberized roofing paint?  Don't want "black", and not really in favor of "silver", but isn't there a white roofing paint?  I'm thinking 2 coats and then as it "wears" apply another coat.?????  Any thoughts out there??